# How to trigger a keydown event?

Tags: javascript

How can I simulate pressing a specific key on the document?

Important: without jQuery

With jQuery:

```
var e = $.Event('keydown');
e.which = 65;
document.trigger(e);
```

But how can I do this without jquery ?

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522769/3073543

Answer (score 0):

Use 'addEventListener' to capture this action

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',keydownfunction,false);

function keydownfunction(event){
// this function triggers on any keydown
}
```

Comment: Falci need fire event, not handle it

Comment: Thanks, but I need to send and not receive.